# Access a struct property

Tags: swift, data-structures

I am learning how to access property in struc. I am trying to access the title property from the categorie struct. I am only able to to business.categories. How can I do to access the title property.

```
struct categorie: Decodable{
    let title: [String] 
}
struct Business: Decodable {
    let name: String = ""
    let categories: [categorie]
}
```

Comment: Show an example (in your question, not in comment) of where/how you want to access the `title` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first. Let's fix your struct names. `struct` declarations should be `CapitalizedCamelCase`, so your struct looks like this:

```
struct Categorie: Decodable{
    let title: [String] 
}
struct Business: Decodable {
    let name: String = ""
    let categories: [Categorie]
}
```

Next, you're looking for the title property of an element in the array of `categories`, so you'd do it like so:

`business.categories[0].title`

You need to specify which element of the array you want to examine. In the example above, I'm getting the 1st element's (`[0]`) `title` property. You'll want to put some logic in to protect against categories being empty.